# Data Studio Table Chart is not sorting correctly

Tags: sorting, google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I have a working chart of podcast episodes by download count in a query. That query is used to create a table chart in Data Studio. The file name formats are as follows: 2020/889-Jan-16-2020-DMP.mp3

Well Episode 1000 isn't showing at the top now in the sorting order. Because it thinks 1000 is less than 999. See table below:

- 2020/999-Jun-24-2020-DMP.mp3
- 2020/998-Jun-23-2020-DMP.mp3
- 2020/997-Jun-22-2020-DMP.mp3
- 2020/996-Jun-21-2020-DMP.mp3
- 2020/995-Jun-18-2020-DMP.mp3
- 2020/994-Jun-17-2020-DMP.mp3
- 2020/993-Jun-16-2020-DMP.mp3
- continuing ...
- 2020/886-Jan-13-2019-DMP.mp3
- 2020/885-Jan-12-2019-DMP.mp3
- 2020/884-Jan-9-2019-DMP.mp3
- 2020/883-Jan-8-2019-DMP.mp3
- 2020/882-Jan-7-2019-DMP.mp3
- 2020/881-Jan-6-2019-DMP.mp3
- 2020/880-Jan-5-2019-DMP.mp3
- 2020/879-Jan-2-2019-DMP.mp3
- 2020/1001-Jun-30-2020-DMP.mp3   <-------Should be at the top of the table
- 2020/1000-Jun-29-2020-DMP.mp3   <-------Should be at the top of the table
- 2019/878-Dec-19-2019-DMP.mp3
- 2019/877-Dec-18-2019-DMP.mp3
- 2019/876-Dec-17-2019-DMP.mp3

Let me know if that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

### 1) [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487)

It can be achieved by adding the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below as the *Sort* field and setting the order to *Descending* (The RegEx extracts the respective number component, for example `1001`):

```
AVG(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, "^\\d+/(\\d+)-") AS NUMBER ) )
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/bcb3874a-0607-4ecf-9381-f0c39b41fc3f) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

### 2) Troubleshooting Calculated Fields (Invalid Formula)

Adding a section on general troubleshooting for [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) based on an [Earlier Post on the Google Data Studio Forum](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/56533325?msgid=56642102):

1. ***Field Editing***: Have a look at whether [Field Editing is Enabled](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7512288) (Although it shouldn't affect creating Data Source Calculated fields);
2. ***Refresh***: [Refresh the Data Source Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7083608) as well as a Fields in the Report;
3. ***Page Reload***: Shortcut - F5;
4. ***Hard Page Reload***: Shortcut - Ctrl + F5;
5. ***Chart-level Calculated Field***: Double check whether using a Chart-level Calculated Field instead of a Data Source-level Calculated Field, resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that doing this worked too - sort date granularity by Year Week

[Sort date granularity by Year Week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s8kf.png)